# Complete online editions of the Church Fathers

Tags: church-fathers, internet, resource-request

Where can one find a complete version of all the Church fathers online or digital?
This is probably not a regular Christianity.SE question, since it is more of an external reference query.

I am more specific looking for Eusebius, and if it can have the verse quotations indexed, even better. (So you could search for Rom 10:17 etc.)

Comment: If you are specifically looking for Eusebius You should Google anti Nicene fathers, If you want a complete list you need to Google Early Church fathers, and Apostolic Church Fathers.

Comment: See if [this link to "The Fathers of the Church"](http://www.newadvent.org/fathers/index.html) is useful for you.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Eusebius&c=books

Comment: http://www.ccel.org, specifically http://www.ccel.org/fathers.html

Comment: Have you tried ccel.org, it has an extensive library?

Comment: Why the downvote for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.ccel.org/fathers.html will give you the complete text of the series of English translations of the church fathers that was put together in the 1800s. They also provide there a link to public domain translations of some more father which were commissioned by Roger Pearse.   Thus, its one stop "shopping" for every translation of the church fathers that is in the Public Domain, and thus free.  Although their list of the additional fathers may lag behind the one found on Roger Pearse's own site: http://www.tertullian.org/fathers/ And on his site, you can order the full collection plus the additional fathers on CD-ROM if you want. I think you can also order a CD-ROM on ccel of every text they have on their site.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this site: http://patristica.net/

Which essentially links to Google scans of the Books by Migne which contains the Latin and Greek of the originals.